# Statsmodel Ljung-Box test for non-zero mean

Tags: statsmodels, white-noise

I have few time series, which I would like to model using ARIMA. But plotting ACF and PACF indicates these series are probably white noise. I am using Ljung-Box test to confirm it. I am implementing it in Python using statsmodel package. However, the documentation of statsmodel say for the series it:

> Assumed to have mean zero

Does this test will give incorrect result if the time-series has non-zero mean or it calculates the mean and then proceeds further?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The statement that mean zero is assumed is incorrect in the development documentation.

The Ljung-Box test is usually used with residuals which have mean zero. However, the test statistic is based on the sum of autocorrelations which are computed from the demeaned data.

So, `acorr_ljungbox` in statsmodels always removes the mean.